# converting series to array

Tags: python, pandas

I was just playing with a data-set of restaurants and I counted the values of locations of different restaurants using `count_values()`, now I need to extract it into array form
my code:

```
location_to_keep = dataset['location'].value_counts()

print(location_to_keep)

output:
BTM                           2181
Koramangala 5th Block         1987
Indiranagar                   1394
HSR                           1329
Jayanagar                     1281
JP Nagar                      1163
Whitefield                     916
Koramangala 7th Block          838
Koramangala 6th Block          813
Marathahalli                   762
Koramangala 4th Block          706
Brigade Road                   699
MG Road                        641
Bannerghatta Road              609
Ulsoor                         597
Koramangala 1st Block          568
Bellandur                      542
Sarjapur Road                  534
Kalyan Nagar                   532
Banashankari                   480
Residency Road                 465
Church Street                  464
Richmond Road                  457
Malleshwaram                   454
Lavelle Road                   437
Basavanagudi                   416
Electronic City                386
Cunningham Road                383
New BEL Road                   338
Frazer Town                    33
```

Need to extract this in array form with the name of the restaurants?
Some reply fast....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: `list(location_to_keep.index)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think @Quang Hoang got it right and `list(location_to_keep.index)` should solve your problem. For the sake of completeness, here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
locations = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
dataset['location'] = np.random.choice(locations, 1000)
```

By using `value_counts` we should get something like below.

```
In [1]: location_to_keep = dataset['location'].value_counts()
        print(location_to_keep)
Out[1]: B    272
        C    259
        D    247
        A    222
        Name: location, dtype: int64
```

Then you can get the names with `index` and the counts with `values`.

```
In [2]: list(location_to_keep.values)
Out[2]: [272, 259, 247, 222]

In [3]: list(location_to_keep.index)
Out[3]: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']
```